# Wierd behaviour with rendering of struts ActionMessage when localized to Portuguese

Tags: localization, struts1

```
ActionMessage message = new ActionMessage("ERRORS_MAX_NUMBER",maxNumber);
```

When this message is finally rendered as HTML, the `maxNumber` is shown in format **1,00,000**.
The `maxNumber` is an int an there is no **','** character in it. And after that when the text is localized to Portuguese the **','** is replaced by **'.'** and hence the number is shown as **1.00.000**

I don't know what is going on. How to explain this behavior?

Comment: What is the type of maxNumber, and its value? What is the value of the message stored under the key ERRORS_MAX_NUMBER? Where do you see 1,00,000 displayed? Where do you see 1.00.000 displayed?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the current locale used to format the message changed after localization. If you want to keep it permanent, you should prefix to a specified locale key for example

```
ActionMessage message = new ActionMessage(Locale.US.toString()+"."+"ERRORS_MAX_NUMBER", maxNumber);
```

would format the message to the locale `"en_US"`.

Comment: The problem was solved when i did
`ActionMessage message = new ActionMessage("ERRORS_MAX_NUMBER",String.valueOf(maxNumber));`

`maxNumber` here is of type int.

Apparently the type of the message is checked when the jsp is served with the localized content and if its a number its formatted by struts/tiles